# SQL counting based on date comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following SQL query which gives me all of my assets which are older than two years, broken down by organization.  Then I have to run it again and just remove the date comparison part in the `WHERE` clause to find out my total number of assets, so I can give a count of old, a count of total, and then a % old.

Is there a way to do this all as a single query?  I'm thinking some type of `case` statement in the query maybe?

```sql
SELECT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, COUNT(DISTINCT a.LabAssetSerialNbr) TotalAssets
FROM vw_DimLabAsset a
INNER JOIN vw_DimWorker w ON w.WorkerKey = a.LabAssetAssignedToWorkerKey
INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd = w.WorkerOrganizationUnitCd
    AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm IS NOT NULL
WHERE a.SystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0)
    AND a.LabAssetTypeNm IN ('u_cmdb_ci_prototype_system', 'u_cmdb_ci_silicon')
    AND a.LabAssetHardwareStatus <> 'retired'
    AND (a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus IS NULL OR a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus <> 'archive')
GROUP BY o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

I tried adding this to the select:  `

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN a.SystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

but that doesn't return the same count as the TotalAssets value.

## Update

Here's the final query I ended up with:

```sql
DECLARE @date DateTime
SELECT @date = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0);

WITH pphw AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, a.LabAssetSerialNbr, MIN(a.SystemCreatedOnDtm) MinCreated
    FROM vw_DimLabAsset a
    INNER JOIN vw_DimWorker w ON a.LabAssetAssignedToWorkerKey = w.WorkerKey
    INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o ON w.WorkerOrganizationUnitCd = o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd
        AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm IS NOT NULL
        AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm IS NOT NULL
    WHERE LabAssetHardwareStatus <> 'Retired'
        AND (LabAssetHardwareSubStatus IS NULL OR LabAssetHardwareSubStatus <> 'Archive')
        AND a.LabAssetTypeNm IN ('u_cmdb_ci_prototype_system', 'u_cmdb_ci_silicon')
    GROUP BY o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, a.LabAssetSerialNbr
)
SELECT OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN MinCreated < @date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AssetsOverTwoYears,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LabAssetSerialNbr) TotalAssets
FROM pphw
GROUP BY OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN MinCreated < @date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: please tag the database you are using

Comment: You mention wanting the COUNT but you are using SUM? Why are you not using COUNT?

Comment: COUNT is going to add one no matter the value.  I used SUM because if the date was less than I returned 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: @Gargoyle I have attempted to answer without sample data, I hope it is correct. Just so I understand, due to the fact that you have a DISTINCT within the COUNT for LabAssetSerialNbr, you have duplicate records by LabAssetSerialNbr. As a result, you want to eliminate the duplicates. Am I correct?

Comment: @JWeezy That's correct.  Working to get rid of those duplicates but unfortunately they do exist right now.

Comment: @Gargoyle OK, then I am confident that the query I have provided will work. Can you run it and let me know?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.SystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0) THEN a.LabAssetSerialNbr ELSE NULL END)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is similar to tysonwright, but I think the GROUP BY clause should be outside of the sub-select. But, I would want sample data to validate this. The bottom line is that you should first gather all of the records that you want calculate metrics on via a sub-select. From there, you can perform your SUMs and COUNTs.

```
SELECT TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm
    ,TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
    ,TotalAssets = COUNT(TMP1.LabAssetSerialNbr)
    ,AssetsOver2YearsOld = SUM(TMP1.AssetOver2YearsOldInd)
    ,PercAssetsOver2YearsOld = SUM(TMP1.AssetOver2YearsOldInd) / COUNT(TMP1.LabAssetSerialNbr)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, a.LabAssetSerialNbr
            ,AssetOver2YearsOldInd = CASE WHEN a.SystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        FROM vw_DimLabAsset a
        INNER JOIN vw_DimWorker w 
            ON w.WorkerKey = a.LabAssetAssignedToWorkerKey
        INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o 
            ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd = w.WorkerOrganizationUnitCd
            AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm IS NOT NULL
        WHERE a.LabAssetTypeNm IN ('u_cmdb_ci_prototype_system', 'u_cmdb_ci_silicon')
            AND a.LabAssetHardwareStatus <> 'retired'
            AND (a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus IS NULL 
                    OR a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus <> 'archive')
        ) TMP1
GROUP BY TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

**Update:**

To remove the duplicates by date time, you can use either the MIN or MAX function, depending one what your requirement is:

```
SELECT TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm
    ,TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
    ,TotalAssets = COUNT(TMP1.LabAssetSerialNbr)
    ,AssetsOver2YearsOld = SUM(CASE WHEN TMP1.MaxSystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ,PercAssetsOver2YearsOld = SUM(CASE WHEN TMP1.MaxSystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(TMP1.LabAssetSerialNbr)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, a.LabAssetSerialNbr, MaxSystemCreatedOnDtm = MAX(a.SystemCreatedOnDtm)
        FROM vw_DimLabAsset a
        INNER JOIN vw_DimWorker w 
            ON w.WorkerKey = a.LabAssetAssignedToWorkerKey
        INNER JOIN vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o 
            ON o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd = w.WorkerOrganizationUnitCd
            AND o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm IS NOT NULL
        WHERE a.LabAssetTypeNm IN ('u_cmdb_ci_prototype_system', 'u_cmdb_ci_silicon')
            AND a.LabAssetHardwareStatus <> 'retired'
            AND (a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus IS NULL 
                    OR a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus <> 'archive')
        GROUP BY o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, a.LabAssetSerialNbr
        ) TMP1
GROUP BY TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, TMP1.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: This seems like it *should* work but the `AssetsOver2YearsOld` isn't matching up with my other query.  Trying to figure out what's going on right now.

Comment: @Gargoyle In this case, I decompose the query by removing the aggregates so that I can see what data is being calculated. So, try running the sub-select to make sure it is giving the correct results first.

Comment: Yup.  Unfortunately the sub-select data is in the thousands, which is making this really painful.

Comment: @Gargoyle Break it down further by a single LabAssetSerialNbr. Add that into the WHERE clause. For example: AND a.LabAssetSerialNbr = 1234

Comment: It's off by however many serial numbers are duplicated...which makes sense because the SUM/CASE is just looking at the age, and the duplicates are all older than two years, so it counts them each twice.

Comment: @Gargoyle So, there are duplicates based on time? When you eliminate the CASE statement, do you get DISTINCT records? If yes, you will need to add a constraint to account for this. How do you want to handle this? Do you want to go by the latest (i.e., MIN) or the earliest (i.e., MAX) datetime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168352/discussion-between-gargoyle-and-j-weezy).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you need:

```
SELECT 
    s.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, 
    s.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm, 
    COUNT(*) TotalAssets,
    SUM(CASE    WHEN s.SystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AssetsOver2YearsOld,
    SUM(CASE    WHEN s.SystemCreatedOnDtm < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(yy, -2, GETDATE())), 0)
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) PercAssetsOver2YearsOld
FROM 
    (   
    SELECT
        o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, 
        o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
        a.LabAssetSerialNbr,
        a.SystemCreatedOnDtm
    FROM    
        vw_DimLabAsset a
    INNER JOIN 
        vw_DimWorker w 
    ON 
        w.WorkerKey = a.LabAssetAssignedToWorkerKey
    INNER JOIN 
        vw_DimOrganizationHierarchy o 
    ON 
        o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitCd = w.WorkerOrganizationUnitCd
    AND 
        o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm IS NOT NULL
    WHERE 
        a.LabAssetTypeNm IN ('u_cmdb_ci_prototype_system', 'u_cmdb_ci_silicon')
    AND 
        a.LabAssetHardwareStatus <> 'retired'
    AND 
        (a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus IS NULL OR a.LabAssetHardwareSubStatus <> 'archive')
    GROUP BY 
        o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelThreeNm, 
        o.OrganizationHierarchyUnitLevelFourNm
        a.LabAssetSerialNbr,
        a.SystemCreatedOnDtm
    ) AS s
```